# Created one session bt it took too time in no more lookup cache to build by additional concurrent pipeline in the current concurrent source set

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-data-integration-hub

What will be the solution for TT_11185 no more lookup cache to build additional concurrent pipeline in the current concurrent source set becuz it taking too much time to run the session

Answer (score 3):

This normally happens when one or more lookup SQLs are taking too long to fetch the data and cache it. You can do below two things -

1. Tune SQL of the lookups. Check the session log carefully, identify which lookup or lookup SQL is taking time. Tune it up by adding more filters or add inner join to the source, remove unwanted columns from lookup, join on indexed columns, order by only keys, put date filter if you think its appropriate. This will help overall performance of the session and your session will take much less time.
   Now, if its a flat file lookup, then try to reduce number of rows in the file.
2. You can set session property `Additional Concurrent Pipelines for Lookup Cache Creation` to Auto or some numeric value like 5. This will ensure your lookups gets cached in parallel so whole session takes less time.
3. You can also increase `DTM Buffer Size` but its not necessary if there is issue with point #1.